# How does filter size affect image understanding

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

How does filter size affect image understanding?
For example, if our data is images of human faces, what is the difference between using a 3 * 3 filter and a 7 * 7 filter?
Does increasing the size of the filter differentiate more shapes and textures?

Comment: it might be me, but I think you should clarify which filter you're referring to exactly.

Comment: I'm talking in general, let's say Sobel filter..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, to some extent.

Increasing the filter kernel allows the model to differentiate between more **complex & bigger shapes and textures**. For example:
`Conv2D(filters=x, kernel_size=(7,7))` can differentiate more shapes than `Conv2D(filters=x, kernel_size=(3,3))` can.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @AliAhmad If this answer helped, you can show your appreciation by voting it. Thank you!